# Reactjs IsNaN not validating inputs correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a readOnly input that calculates a value based on two other inputs (qty and price). In the getLineTotal() function, I am trying to validate the inputs and am having an issue when the input receives a blank value.

```
const getLineTotal = (e: any): void => {
        let parsedPrice: number;
        console.log(typeof e.target.value)
        if(Number.isNaN(e.target.value)){
            console.log("yes")
            parsedPrice = 0;
        }
        else{
            parsedPrice = parseInt(e.target.value);
        }
        setPrice(parsedPrice);
        console.log(qty, parsedPrice, "=>", qty * parsedPrice)
        setTotal(qty * parsedPrice);
    }
```

I have tried multiple different methods of detecting this NaN value, but nothing has worked. The console says it's a string but then says received NaN for value attribute.

```
string
LineDetail.tsx:38 12 12 '=>' 144
LineDetail.tsx:29 string
LineDetail.tsx:38 12 NaN '=>' NaN
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `e.target.value` is a string, and therefore `Number.isNaN` will always be false. You need to check *after* you used `parseInt`.

Comment: That worked, SMH at myself lol